# Difference between delimited and undelimited continuations

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming, continuations

I guess the difference between `delimited` and `undelimited` continuations is like the difference between `call` and `jump`.

If we invoke `delimited` continuation it will return to the caller once it finishes. If we invoke `undelimited` continuation it works like `goto` and never returns to the caller.

Does it make sense? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're a bit off track. Continuations, of either flavor, have nothing much to do with `goto` (jumps). They have everything to do with the stack, however.

---

*Classic Continuations*

Remember regular continuations capture the notion of a control stack as a first class values. Stacks may be named, passed around as arguments, and values may be applied to them, yielding a change in control flow, with a simple API based on function application via `callCC`.

*Delimited Continuations*

What do *delimited* continuations add to the mix?

Recall that regular continuations capture the entire call stack up to a certain point. What if we could put markers in that say exactly how much of the control stack to capture in the continuation? A sort of "delimit"ing of the control stack.

That's the idea, and now you have super-cool delimited continuations: delimit, capture and manipulate arbitrary portions of a program, as a value. Perfect for resumption and incremental processing, and other tricky forms of control flow.

*References*

- Regular, ["undelimited" continuations.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library/CC-delcont#Undelimited_continuations)
- [Delimited continuations.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Library/CC-delcont#Delimited_continuations)
- Oleg's papers on [delimited control](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/index.html)
- [PFPL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf), ch33.

*Notes*

Some corrections from [Oleg Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/), received off-list:

- Continuations and jumps are deeply related, the first discoveries of continuations were in the context of trying to understand the semantics of jumps, or goto. Landin's `J` operator was introduced precisely for that purpose; J is the precursor of call/cc. See [An Introduction to Landin’s
  “A Generalization of Jumps and Labels”](http://www.brics.dk/~hosc/local/HOSC-11-2-pp117-123.pdf)
- Further reading on [undelimited, "regular" continuations](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/undelimited.html), in "Undelimited continuations are co-values rather than functions", and their foundations.

Comment: On `J`, see Danvy, Shan, and Zerny's "J is for JavaScript: A direct-style correspondence between Algol-like languages and JavaScript using first-class continuations": http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/j/dsz.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Continuations as a language feature (as opposed to continuations as a programming pattern) are reifications of (parts of) the control context ("the stack"). As Don said, undelimited continuations represent the whole context, whereas delimited continuations only represent part of it.

Typically, capturing an undelimited continuation (eg, with `call/cc`) doesn't change the control context; the control context is only changed when the continuation is invoked (ie, reflected onto the stack).

Typically, capturing a delimited continuation (eg, with `shift`) immediately aborts the segment of the control context up to the nearest delimiter (eg, `reset`) and reifies that as what seems to be a plain old function (although it might be implemented as stack trickery rather than however normal functions are implemented).

BTW, continuations are sometimes called "first-class jumps", but that doesn't mean they have any more to do with the `jmp` instruction than a normal function call does.